# Can I use VBA to copy a picture that is above the page I found in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hello I am trying to automate a process in vba and I'm not sure if it is possible.  I have a vba script that move some data around from different worksheets and recently got asked if it was possible to copy and paste from word.  I found a way to open the word document and find the data and lets say it finds it on page 9 of the word doc then I need to go to the page before page 8 and copy the picture from that page to the excel sheet.  is this possible?

here is my code to find the word in word:

```
Sub FindAndGoToWord()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim foundRange As Object

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
    
    With wordDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "dog"
        .MatchWholeWord = True 
        .Execute
        
        
        If .Found Then
            Set foundRange = wordApp.Selection.Range
            foundRange.Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comments to the code so you can understand what's going on. This assumes that Word is already running, with an open Document, with the word "dog" in it (or whatever word you will really use), and that the previous page actually includes a picture (as an InlineShape) ... if the previous page includes multiple pictures then the first is copied.

```
Sub FindAndGoToWord()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim foundRange As Object

    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") ' assumes Word is already running with a Document open with the word "dog" in it
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
    
    ' check we are showing the document in 'pages' and repaginate just in case
    If wordDoc.ActiveWindow.View.Type <> 3 Then ' 3 = wdPrintView
        MsgBox "Not in print layout"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    wordDoc.Repaginate
            
    With wordDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "dog"
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Execute
        
        If .Found Then
            Set foundRange = wordApp.Selection.Range
            foundRange.Select
            
            ' get the page number of the selection and check it is valid
            Dim lPage As Long
            lPage = wordApp.Selection.Information(3) - 1 ' 3 = wdActiveEndPageNumber
            If lPage = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Cannot get page before page 1"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            ' go to the previous page
            wordApp.Selection.GoTo What:=1, Which:=3, Count:=1 ' 1 = wdGoToPage; 3 = wdGoToPrevious
            Dim rngPage As Object ' Word.Range
            Set rngPage = wordDoc.Bookmarks("\page").Range
            
            ' if the previous page has a picture then copy it to the clipboard (if it has multiple this will copy the first)
            If rngPage.InlineShapes.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox "No pictures found on page " & lPage
                Exit Sub
            End If
            rngPage.InlineShapes.Item(1).Range.CopyAsPicture

            ' paste into Excel
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: John what is this line doing? - Set rngPage = wordDoc.Bookmarks("\page").Range
            and I got it to work by changing:
            rngPage.InlineShapes.Item(1).Range.CopyAsPicture
            to: rngPage.CopyAsPicture

Thank You for your Help.

Comment: Ah ... you wanted the whole page as a picture ... not the picture that is embedded within the page? Okay ...

Comment: That line is setting `rngPage` to the whole page ... `"\page"` is a [Predefined Bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks) for the current page